# Yield a two separate .rb files in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

I'm new to rails. I would like to yield my "_posts" form next to my database results. How can I do this?

I am currently yielding the index.html.erb by default twice using this but I want the second to be the _form.html.erb file so that I can write a post while watching the database:

```
<tr>
<td><%= yield %></td>
<td><%= yield %></td>
</tr>
```

Eventually I hope to refresh both the form and the list of posts with ajax. but that's for later.

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr>
<td><%= yield %></td>
<td><%= render :partial => "form" %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks already. But when i use this I get the error: "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" on the line of "form" that says: "1: <%= form_for(@word) do |f| %>" What is going wrong here?

Comment: @Benjamin you need to specify `@word`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your _posts form is already in a partial and so you can include that partial in the template for your index page:

In index.html.erb include:

```
<%= render( :partial => "<model-name>/<partial_name>" %>
```

Where `<model_name>` is that of the model your posts form references and `<partial_name>` is the name of the partial (i.e. the filename of where you have the form.

e.g.

```
<%= render( :partial => "posts/new" %>
```

A partial is simply denoted by adding an underscore to the start of the filename. i.e. if before it was `new.html.erb` then make it `_new.html.erb`.

There is lots of good information on partials and rendering in the Rails docs:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not yield - which is usually used in layout - but render template.